# Handling a very large table without index

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a very large table 20-30 million rows that is completely overwritten each time it is updated by the system supplying the data over which I have no control.

- The table is not sorted in a particular order.
- The rows in the table are unique, there is no subset of columns that I can be assured to have unique values.

Is there a way I can run a `SELECT` query followed by a `DELETE` query on this table with a fixed limit without having to trigger any expensive sorting/indexing/partitioning/comparison whilst being certain that I do not delete a row not covered by the previous select.

Comment: using a LIMIT without ORDER BY Is unsound because MySQL can return the records in random order.

Comment: I could not find a reference confirming this but thought so much. The best I have come up with is to either do the `SELECT` and `DELETE` using `ORDER BY`. I've also tried to do `ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;` Both work, both are slow (> 5 minutes) so I'm really looking for a faster alternative.

Comment: You used `SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1000000` right? Try `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 1000000 ORDER BY id ASC` this query should be executed as a range scan and might execute faster..

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I was not sure if `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` would just use some deterministic sorting method, but without any documentation I never used that. Sorting performed faster than creating an index if I have less than 6m rows or have 6 `SELECT`s and 6 `DELETE`s. Adding the index was faster when working with more data rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE x = 1 AND y = 3;

DELETE * FROM MyTable WHERE NOT (x = 1 AND y = 3);
```

In other words, use `NOT` against the same search expression you used in the first query to get the complement of the set of rows. This should work for most expressions, unless some of your terms return NULL.

If there are no indexes, then both the SELECT and DELETE will incur a table-scan, but no sorting or temp tables.

---

Re your comment:

Right, unless you use `ORDER BY`, you aren't guaranteed anything about the order of the rows returned. Technically, the storage engine is free to return the rows in any arbitrary order.

In practice, you will find that InnoDB at least returns rows in a somewhat predictable order: it reads rows in some index order. Even if your table has no keys or indexes defined, *every* InnoDB table is stored as a clustered index, even if it has to [generate an internal key called `GEN_CLUST_ID` behind the scenes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html). That will be the order in which InnoDB returns rows.

But you shouldn't rely on that. The internal implementation is not a contract, and it could change tomorrow.

Another suggestion I could offer:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableBase (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  A INT,
  B DATE,
  C VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE VIEW MyTable AS SELECT A, B, C FROM MyTableBase;
```

With a table and a view like above, your external process can believe it's overwriting the data in `MyTable`, but it will actually be stored in a base table that has an additional primary key column. This is what you can use to do your SELECT and DELETE statements, and order by the primary key column so you can control it properly.

Comment: No I'd ideally want to `SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 1000000` followed by a matching `DELETE FROM MyTable LIMIT 1000000`. But as Raymond Nijland commented above that's not assured to affect the same rows.